# EF DbContext update entity collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This is how my domain looks:

```
public abstract class Field
    {
        //PK
        public int FieldId { get; set; }        
        //FK
        [ForeignKey("FieldConfig")]
        public int FieldConfigId { get; set; }
        //Relations
        public virtual FieldConfig FieldConfig { get; set; }
    }

public class FieldConfig
    {
        //PK
        public int FieldConfigId { get; set; }
        //Columns
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //FK
        [ForeignKey("LabelType")]
        public int? LabelTypeId { get; set; }
        //Relations
        public virtual LabelType LabelType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Field> Fields { get; set; }
    }
```

What I want to do is the following:
Updata a FieldConfig its Fields, this is How I try to do it:

```
FieldConfig fc = labelTypeRepo.FindById(fieldConfig.LabelTypeId).FieldConfigs.SingleOrDefault(f => f.FieldConfigId == fieldConfig.FieldConfigId);
            fc.Name = fieldConfig.Name;
fc.Fields = NewFields;
labelTypeRepo.SaveChanges();
```

when I do this it adds in my database 3 new fields instead of the normal ids so it looks like this:
1 - oldfield
2 - oldfield
3 - oldfield
4 - newfield
5 - newfield
6 - newfield

then I tried first deleting the old elements like this:

```
foreach (Field f in fc.Fields.ToList())
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.DeleteObject(f);
```

that worked but when I added the new Fields they got an other Id obviously...

So my question is how can I update this collection without adding new fields while maintaining the Id's? (not that i'm using DbContext as context)

I already checked that I'm always using the same context.

Thx for the help..

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided here are my toughts:

```
fc.Fields = NewFields;
```

I can't see these `NewFields` collection anywhere but I suspect they are not a modified version of the current fc.Fields. If the `FieldId` is auto generated, when you provide new values with the same id's as the old ones EF will not modify them but will insert new values instead.

Here's what I think you want to do:

```
FieldConfig fc = ...;
fc.Name = fieldConfig.Name;

foreach(var field in fc.Fields)
{
    /*Modify each field properties with the corresponding properties of Newfields, e.g.:
      var newField = NewFields.First(nf => nf.FieldId == field.FieldId);
      field.FieldConfig = newField.FieldConfig;
    */
}
labelTypeRepo.SaveChanges();
```

Hope it helps.